# Object variable of with block variable not Set

Tags: excel, vba, function, set

I am a novice in vba who currently designing some sorts of automated Matrix system in excel. I tried both sets of codes in a Worksheet and it runs perfectly. But,when i try to use the same code in an event sub in an userform, an **error 91** popped out and showed an error in `orivalue`, though I already assign a value to it. Also I will highlight the debug lines according to the compiler.

Here are the codes for the function.

```
Function find_prevconfig(x2 As Integer) As Range
    For y = 0 To 30
        If Range("E590").Offset(y, x2) = "Y" Then
            Set find_preconfig = Range("C590").Offset(y, 0)
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next y
End Function
```

And here is the event sub that i called the function to:

```
Private Sub btn_confirm_Click()
    Dim orivalue As Range
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 0 To 30
        If Range("E26").Offset(0, i).Value = Range("J6").Value Then
            Set orivalue = find_prevconfig(i)
            MsgBox (orivalue)
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

The debug line is `MsgBox (orivalue)` as it said `orivalue = nothing`. Your help and advices are really much appreciated!

Comment: If the `If range("E590").Offset(y, x2) = "Y" Then` condition fails, the `find_prevconfig()` function returns default value (`Nothing`), which is the reason

Comment: The context matters. i.e. when the event runs, which sheet are you on.

Comment: @АлексейР as i set up the value in the target Ranges, i will put at least one "Y". So the condition will always be met. if  i add `msgbox(find_prevconfig)` in the function block codes, it run perfectly and the value that i search will be found correctly. The problem is when calling and assigning the function value to an object in the event sub

Comment: @shahkalpesh i tried first declaring the worksheet that i intended to search using `Thisworkbook.sheets("sheet1")`. But still when i called the value of the function in the event sub, the same error keep poppin out.

Comment: What happens if you try `If Trim(UCase(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E590").Offset(y, x2).Value)) = "Y" Then` instead of `If range("E590").Offset(y, x2) = "Y" Then`?

Comment: @siddharthRout thanks for the extra tips. But it still an error which i think has something to do when calling and assigning the function value to an object in the event sub. I would say the function block code is correct.

Comment: @siddharthRout the `option explicit` is a game changer. Just realized how many objects that I did not declare and went to define it directly. Thanks for the help.

Comment: A suggestion: Always have it on by default. Whenever you open a new code module, VBA will automatically insert it for you. I have spoken about it [HERE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lftEbmYwh-U&t=1010s)

Comment: @siddharthrout just one small question. incase i encounter almost the same type of error, how can i solve "the object variable or With block variable not set" or Error "91" in general?

Comment: Ensure that you check if the object exists before you use it. For example in your case `MsgBox (orivalue)` should be written as `If Not orivalue Is Nothing Then MsgBox orivalue.Value Else MsgBox "Object is Nothing"`

Comment: @SiddharthRout then if the `orivalue` should theoretically has a value and not `Nothing` then is it because of any wrong spelling in the referencing or object?

Comment: Yup. If you do the two changes that I mentioned above (Option Explicit + correct errors and checking if the Object is not Nothing) then your code should work. Also it is a good habit to click on the menu `Debug | Compile VBA project` before you run the project. I believe and I could be wrong but this is one of the most under utilized feature of VBA. It checks if the code in the workbook is syntactically correct.

Comment: @SiddharthRout Great! thanks again for the help and tips.

Comment: I am posting a detailed answer. Almost done.

Answer (score 1):

> the object variable or With block variable not set" or Error "91"

There are few things that I will address.

**1.** Regarding the error, you need to check if the object exists before you use it. For example

The line `MsgBox (orivalue)` should be written as

```
Set orivalue = find_prevconfig(i)
If Not orivalue Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox orivalue.Value
Else
    MsgBox "Object is Nothing"
End If
```

**2.** Your object `find_prevconfig` will always be `Nothing` even if the condition is True. And that is because of a typo. Function name is `find_prevconfig` but you are using `find_preconfig`. It is advisable to always use `Option Explicit`

**3.** Fully qualify your objects. In your code if you do not do that, then it will refer to the active sheet and the active sheet may not be the sheet that you are expecting it to be. For example `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E590").Offset(y, x2)`

**4.** Even though, `.Value` is the default property of a range when you are assigning a value or reading a value, it is advisable to use it explicitly. I personally believe it is a good habit. Will help you avoid lot of headaches in the future when you are quickly skimming the code. `Set rng = Range("SomeRange")` vs `SomeValue = Range("SomeRange").Value` or `SomeValue = Range("SomeRange").Value2`

**5.** When you are doing a string comparison, it is advisable to consider that the strings can have spaces or can be of different case. `"y"` is not equal to `"Y"`. Similarly, `"Y "` is not equal to `"Y"`. I, if required, use `TRIM` and `UCASE` for this purpose as shown in the code below.

Your code can be written as (**UNTESTED**)

```
Option Explicit

Function find_prevconfig(x2 As Long) As Range
    Dim y As Long
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    '~~> Change sheet as applicable
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    For y = 0 To 30
        If Trim(UCase(ws.Range("E590").Offset(y, x2).Value2)) = "Y" Then
            Set rng = ws.Range("C590").Offset(y)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next y
    
    Set find_prevconfig = rng
End Function

Private Sub btn_confirm_Click()
    Dim orivalue As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    '~~> Change sheet as applicable
    '~~> You can also pass the worksheet as a parameter if the comparision is
    '~~> in the same sheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    For i = 0 To 30
        If ws.Range("E26").Offset(0, i).Value = ws.Range("J6").Value Then
            Set orivalue = find_prevconfig(i)
            
            '~~> Msgbox in a long loop can be very annoying. Use judiciously
            If Not orivalue Is Nothing Then
                'MsgBox orivalue.Value
                Debug.Print orivalue.Value
            Else
                'MsgBox "Object is Nothing"
                Debug.Print "Object is Nothing"
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```